# R shiny: expressing an equation in a plot title using a string obtained by ui

Tags: r, plot, shiny, title, equation

I have written the following r code:

```
remove(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Plot a function'),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("func", "Function to plot:", value = "x"),
    numericInput("xMin", "Set the minimum of x: ", value = 0),
    numericInput("xMax", "Set the maximum of x: ", value = 10),
    submitButton("Plot")
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    x <- seq(input$xMin, input$xMax, 0.01)
    f <- function(x) {
      eval(parse(text = input$func))
    }
    y <- f(x)
    df <- data.frame(x, y)
    theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 12))
    figure <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
      geom_line() +
      labs(x = "x",
           y = "y",
           title = parse(text = input$func)) +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(.6, .6, .6, .6), "cm"),
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    plot(figure)
    filename <- "plotFunction.jpeg"
    ggsave(filename,
           width = 6,
           height = 4,
           dpi = 200)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When the user enters `x^2 - 2` to specify the function, I obtain the following output:

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqGyE.png)

I want the title of the plot to start with `y =` (so that the whole title will become `y = x^2 - 2` with `x^2` rendered properly), but I have been unable to do so.  For instance, if I concatenate the user input string with `y =`, the title becomes `(= y, x^2 - 2)` (although `x^2` is rendered properly).

Comment: just modify `title` in ggplot as `parse(text = paste("y =",input$func)))`

Comment: @parth It does not work.  With the change, the title becomes =(y, x^2 - 2) (with x^2 properly rendered).

Comment: @parth `==` :-)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, thnx for fixing _typo_, got ur point (y)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent It works.  Thank you.

Comment: @mozartbeethovenbrahms Then you can accept my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
labs(title = parse(text=paste0("y == ", input$func)))
```

Comment: Laurent It works.  Thank you!  Can you give me any reference for it?